# How to preallocate memory when creating pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

During the execution of my job I want to build a pandas DataFrame with its internal state at each step of execution. I want to do that because I want to be able to use the DataFrame later to do some analysis. So, that's the context: I start with an empty DataFrame and, after the job has finishing producing all its data, the final DataFrame size is 7GB (at most).

These are the approaches I've tried this far:

1. I can maintain a list of lists, my job keeps appending new rows to that list. At the end I run something like: `df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=list("abc"))`. This is the fastest method, but it's very wasteful in terms of memory usage.
2. I don't use the lists of lists anymore, but, instead I keep calling `df = df.append([{"a": 1.0, "b": 1.0, "c": "hello"}])`. This starts off ok, but as the DataFrame grows a lot of memory copying starts happening and it becomes really slow.

So, neither of them are ideal. I can estimate the final size of the DataFrame before my job runs (I think I can usually match the size precisely, to be honest), so I would like to tell pandas to allocate the entire memory ahead (or at least a large enough chunk to last for a while) and then, I'd like a method similar to `df.append` that will just add the new row at the end of the preallocated memory. Ideally, it would be smart enough to resize memory, if needed.

I may be grossly missing something, but I sincerly couldn't find a way to do that anywhere I looked.

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this?  It's not entirely clear why you can't let the df grow as you add real data to it.

Comment: Isn't that what I did in the approach (2)? How can the df grow without moving data around? That's my problem. My job is a simulation that doesn't use pandas, currently. I can try some other solution like writing log data to a file, then read from pandas. I was hoping to have a simpler architecture, though.

Comment: what's wrong with approach 2?  what would be the benefit of reserving memory?

Comment: 7GB isn't that big. Memory is cheap. Also, if you're using Jupyter, it has terrible memory management, garbage collection doesn't really work there. Finally, the dtypes in pandas are mostly 64 bit, so that will quickly balloon your memory usage. If possible, specify a lower dtype, like int or float 32, 16, or 8. Just depends on your data.

Comment: @Chris approach 2 is really slow because of all the copies (the simulation takes 70 minutes with that one, whereas it could take only 16 minutes with the appending to lists approach)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney lol I think I'm just poor then. My laptop only has 16GB of RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use approach 1, but every time you get to (say) 10000 rows, convert the list of lists to a DataFrame, append the dataframe to a list of dataframes, and clear your list of lists (by setting it to []). At the end, take your list of df chunks and `pd.concat` them together.

Comment: After that I ran `pd.concat(dfs).reset_index().drop(columns="index")` at the end. Not sure if there's a more efficient way. But tis worked well. My algorithm now takes 30min. and uses only 12GB of RAM :)